# How to use javascript var with # signature to point id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to use javascript var with # signature to point id ?

I tried to use `$("#test_input_val").remove();` as same as `$("#555").remove();` but not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/L1dx3nLb/2/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var test_input_val = document.getElementById("test_input").value;    
        $("#test_input_val").remove();
    });
});
</script>

<body>

<input id="test_input" value="555"/>
<div id="555">test test test test test</div>
<br>

<button>Remove div element</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `test_input_val` is a variable, You need to concatenate and create a valid selector. then various operation can be performed.

```
 $("#" + test_input_val).remove();
```

As per current implementation is looking for element with id `test_input_val`, hence operation is not performed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var test_input_val = document.getElementById("test_input").value;
    $("#" + test_input_val).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="test_input" value="555" />
<div id="555">test test test test test</div>
<br>

<button>Remove div element</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This `$("#test_input_val")` looks for an DOM node which has an ID `test_input_val` and it is not there, so it doesn't work. The issue is you have put a variable in a string, so you have to concatenate it:

```
$("#" + test_input_val).remove();
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var test_input_val = document.getElementById("test_input").value;
    $("#" + test_input_val).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="test_input" value="555" />
<div id="555">test test test test test</div>
<br>

<button>Remove div element</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                var test_input_val = document.getElementById("test_input").value;
                $("#"+test_input_val).remove();
            });
        });



    });




</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="test_input" value="555"/>
<div id="555">test test test test test</div>
<br>

<button>Remove div element</button>


</body>
</html>
```